# Why do I need to use `return` for the recursion to work?

Tags: python, recursion

This is a part of recursion coding challenge I have on Hackerrank. I understand the notion. Yet, not quite for this part and I struggled for quite sometime. Please explain to me!

This code bit won't work:

```
    if n < 1:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = n * factorial(n-1)
    print(n)
```

But if I use `return`, it will work.

Why is it? For me, they're quite the same in this case.

Comment: You need return so value at `n * factorial(n-1)` is returned, otherwise it will expand to `n * None` which is obviously wrong

Comment: @Gulliver 's answer will give you some working code. However I think you haven't quite understand what recursion is and how it works. You better of to read about recursion (there are several online resources available). Do note tho that recursion is not always a good choice in terms of performance but rather a convenient way to solve a problem sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `n * factorial(n - 1)` will multiply `n` by the returned value of `factorial(n - 1)`. If you do not use a `return` statement, then you multiply `n` by `None` which is not the expected behaviour.

The correct program is thus:

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n < 1:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = n * factorial(n - 1)
    return result
```

or more concisely

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n < 1: return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Comment: Or `return 1 if n < 1 else factorial(n - 1)` — although since Python’s conditional statement is syntactically backwards I usually prefer `if … else …`.

Comment: `return 1 if n < 1 else n * factorial(n - 1)` but yeah I agree